# Unable to communicate on Non RealTek Network Adaptors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, udp, nic

I am facing a weird problem...my PC has a RealTek PCIe GBE Family Controller Network card. I am trying to send data over UDP to my target embedded board using my own custom made GUI. Whenever wireshark is open in my PC, I can communicate successfully. However, if Wireshark is off, I cant communicate.

Also, on other PCs having a non-Realtek adaptor, I cant communicate with the target board even if Wireshark is open. Wireshark doesnt show any packets being sent by the GUI to the board. I have tried reinstalling both, Wireshark and Winpcap drivers but the issue still persists.  I also have the latest drivers for my network card installed on my PC. 
For sending data over UDP, the GUI is developed using MS Visual Studio 2008 using winsock library 2.0. I have used standard UDP protocol APIs for performing all the UDP operations.

Is the issue related to Wireshark or Network card or something else?
Please assist.